# SQL Default trace not deleting files above the max no of trace files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, errors, profiler, trace

We have a Sql server 2016 Sp2. Noticed the trace file path D:\Data\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_298.trc is getting filled with trace files and the files are more than 2 months old. To my understanding the max number of trace files should be 5 and if that is the case why it is not deleting files above 5 max trace files.

The only option for me is to disable the default trace. Please advice if there are settings where I can check or any other option I can implement to that the Log drive don't get filled up.

Comment: I am thinking that setting you are referring to  does size management of a trace running at some point in time without stopping.  In other words, there is no auto cleanup of trace files  and you have to manage the cleanup of old .trc files yourself.  I think in your situation, you may need to start and stop the trace and provide some type of script that cleans up files older than a particular time period you need to keep.

Comment: As far as I know the Max number of files supposed to be 5 but it is not deleting anything and retaining all the files.

Comment: Do you perhaps have more than one trace running with the same file name? What does this query return :`SELECT path, is_default, max_size, max_files FROM sys.traces;`\